# How to add component to page - Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently busy with a program where you can 'design' a mobile application in a web application.

My question is how I can open my Component-object in a page(viewChild)?

I have a list with PageComponents, here beneath is the class PageComponent

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  pageName : string;
  components: Array<BaseComponentComponent>[]

  constructor() { 
  }

  public setPageName(name: string) {
    this.pageName = name;
  }

  public getPageName() {
    return this.pageName;
  }
}
```

HTML of PageComponent

```
<p>
  {{pageName}}
</p>
```

Nothing special so far, but I want to open the PageComponent that is clicked in the list.

I tried to do it with ComponentFactoryResolver, but it makes a whole new instance of a PageComponent, so that didn't help.

```
openPage(page: PageComponent) {
    let test = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(page);
    this.parent.clear();

    let componentRef = this.parent.createComponent(test);
}
```

Is it possible to display the Component-object you have to a page?

Comment: Can you put the dom code? What is the local variable you are using to access the basecomponent

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the components of PageComponent so far... the PageComponent's view only has a <p>{{pageName}}</p>

Comment: What do you mean by "open my Component-object" ?

Comment: I have a PageComponent instance already, with all the data in it... I want to open that instance in a view.

Comment: You can place child component tag in parent html.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `ViewChild` on the host (parent) view, like this:

```
<div #page></div>
```

Now, you need to reference it inside your component:

```
@ViewChild('page', {read: ViewContainerRef}) page: ViewContainerRef;
```

Now you can insert your component, if it's all set:

```
this.page.insert(this.componentRef.hostView);
```